# is it possible to crop cover images in buddypress?

Tags: images, buddypress, cropping

Hi i'm using `buddypress v2.7.4`, i can do crop avatar image but not the cover image. Is it possible to crop that cover images ? i saw these directories have different files

`wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-templates/bp-legacy/buddypress/assets/_attachments/`

there're avatars folder and cover-images folder, the avatars folder have `camera.php` and `crop.php` but the `cover-images` only have `index.php` so i try to copy from avatar to cover-images, but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

The cover picture is not intended to be cropped.
When you use this feature, the component tells you which min. image size should be used. If it comes up or not is depends largely of your theme and wp settings.

---

> [buddyPress-cover-photo.php](https://github.com/Twizanex/cover-image/blob/master/wds-bp-cover-photo.php)